# Javascript Formula Calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm currently setting up a few formula calculators. On the one I have this formula:

vc=ds*π.ns/60000

with this script:

```
<script>
    (function () {
    function calculateVc(ds, ns) {
    return (ds * 3.14159265359 * ns / 60000);
    }

    var Vc = document.getElementById("VC");
    if (Vc) {
    Vc.onsubmit = function () {
        this.Vc.value = calculateVc(this.ds.value, this.ns.value);
        return false;
    };
    }
    }());
    </script>
```

Which works perfectly. And then I have the reverse formula: ns=vc*60000/(ds*π) with this script:

```
<script>
    (function () {
function calculateNs(ds, vc) {

    return (vc * 60000 / ds * 3.14159265359);
}

var Ns = document.getElementById("Ns");
if (Ns) {
    Ns.onsubmit = function () {
        this.ns.value = calculateNs(this.ds.value, this.vc.value);
        return false;
    };
}
    }());
    </script>
```

Which doesn't work as required. Reusing the first result in a backward formula gives different results than expected. I suppose it's either a formatting error or a typo.

Comment: How is this off-topic? 

"Ask about...

Specific programming problems
Software algorithms
Coding techniques
Software development tools"

I asked a relevant question and even got a relevant answer. Do you guys just make up rules as you go along? Or is it a "seems to me personally" situation?

Comment: You might want to keep reading past that point: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

Comment: So is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php for example, yet I see a significant difference in the reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add a pair of parentheses:

```
return (vc * 60000 / ( ds * 3.14159265359 ));
```

Comment: Already tried that. No luck.

Comment: I think Andrew is right http://jsfiddle.net/sR5Sd/ , can you give an example of inputs that is not working for?

Comment: I apologise. It was a browser cache issue. You are both perfectly correct. Thank you very much!