# Adding line break in txt file not working

Tags: php, text, line, break

I have a php file which adds click track data to a .txt file. Problem is, each time data is added, it's added on the same line, even though I've added the `"r\n"`:

```
<?php
    $src = isset($_GET['src']) ? $_GET['src'] : "-";
    $dst = isset($_GET['dst']) ? $_GET['dst'] : "-";
    $f = fopen('clickReport.txt',"a+");
    fwrite ($f, date('Y-m-d H:i'));
    fwrite ($f, " : " + $src + " : " + $dst + "\r\n");
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Text file output:

```
2014-02-05 01:1702014-02-05 01:1702014-02-05 01:1702014-02-05 01:170
```

Of course I would like it to be:

```
2014-02-05 01:170
2014-02-05 01:170
2014-02-05 01:170
2014-02-05 01:170
```

etc...

Comment: your mixing js syntax with php its `.` not `+`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a new line to file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
fwrite ($f, " : " + $src + " : " + $dst + " _ " + "\r\n");
```

with this:

```
fwrite ($f," : ".$src." : ".$dst." _ "."\r\n");
```