# How break a line of code

Tags: php, html, line, break

I am trying to break the line after this code. I can't figure it out what ever I do the output of my code is just as shown below:

Output:

> User: adminLogged in: 2014-02-09 05:34:30User: adminLogged OUT:
>   2014-02-09 05:34:36User: tataLogged in: 2014-02-09 05:34:41User:
>   tataLogged OUT: 2014-02-09 05:34:43

I want to set some space and new line.

```
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updatefile = "userlogs.txt";  
$fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "User: $username";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData");
$stringData = "Logged in: $date";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData");
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Please read this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php

Comment: Add "/n" to your lines. It's called a newline. Unless your environment is a browser, not a terminal - then you could use <br>

Comment: `fwrite($fh, "$stringData\n");`. or better yet: `fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 1):

Just make use of `\n` or `\r` in front of your `fwrite()`.

Like this.

```
fwrite($fh, "\n$stringData");
              ^-------- // Add this to both of your fwrite() calls
```

Comment: its still not working same output :((

Comment: output ?? . I gave the solution for input as for the future datum.

Comment: My guess would be windows = \r\n

Comment: @Crazysheep, Right. or just `\r` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updatefile = "userlogs.txt";  
$fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "User: $username";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData\n");
$stringData = "Logged in: $date";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData\n");
fclose($fh);
```

Here you just add `\n` before or after variable assign just like this `fwrite($fh, "$stringData\n");` or `fwrite($fh, "\n$stringData");`.

For more details, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php).