# php wont write correctly to textfile

Tags: php, text-files

so i have the following code:

```
myarray[1] = item1, element1, element2
myarray[2] = item2, element1, element2

$outfile = "csv.txt";
$filewriter = fopen($outfile, "w"); // open for write
foreach($myarray as $item) {
    fwrite($filewriter, $item);
}
```

which produces the following in the txt file:

item1,element1,element2item2,element1,element2

if i try to use "\n" it produces this output:

```
item1,element1,element2
(blank line)
item2,element1,element2
```

how do i get it too:

```
item1,element1,element2
item2,element1,element2
```

This is the \n

```
function writetofile($myarray){
$outfile = "csv.txt"; 
$filewriter = fopen($outfile,"w"); // open for write
$item=$myarray[0]."\n".$myarray[1];
fwrite($filewriter, $item);
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your version which uses `\n`.

Comment: fwrite($filewriter, $item."\n"); -> double quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php p.s. -> foreach($myarray as $item) {
    fwrite($filewriter, $item."\n");
}

Comment: still produces the output with a blank line between each

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code below

```
<?php
$myarray[1] = 'item1, element1, element2';
$myarray[2] = 'item2, element1, element2';

$outfile = "csv.txt";
$filewriter = fopen($outfile, "w"); // open for write
foreach($myarray as $item) {
    fwrite($filewriter, $item.'
');
}
```

Comment: using the code it produces:

item1,2,element2,3
(blank line)
item2,2,element2,3
(blank line)

Comment: must be a problem with another bit of my code then hmmm

Comment: fwrite($filewriter, $item.'
'); this is nothing but it adds ENTER at the end of line, so new line just start from next line and adds enter again as so on, dont leave any spaces before **');**

Comment: foreach($myarray as $item) {
    fwrite($filewriter, $item.'
');

is still producing blank lines in between

Comment: ^ yeah but doesn't make a difference to the output which is annoying

Comment: Sir, the above code is working fine, there is some problem with notepad maybe :P try to open with notepad++ or any other good editor

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
<?php
$myarray = array("item1 ,", "element1 ,", "element2 \r\n","item2 ,","element1 ,","element2");
$array_length = count($myarray); // Array length
$outfile = "csv.txt";
$filewriter = fopen($outfile, "w");


for($x=0;$x<$array_length;$x++)
  {
    echo $myarray[$x];
  fwrite($filewriter, $myarray[$x]);

  }

?>
```

The following code gives you (`csv.txt`) :

```
item1 ,element1 ,element2 
item2 ,element1 ,element2
```

Comment: @user3329114 Can't get you. Do you mean you are `reading $myarray[1] & $myarray[2]` from text file?

Comment: so the array is populated by reading in line by line a textfile