# String adding new lines and I don't understand why

Tags: php, fwrite

I have got this code to open each file in a folder, decrease a value by 5 and then overwrite the existing content.

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("users/*.php") as $filename) {    
        $array = file($filename);

        $wallet = $array[0];
        $time = $array[1];
        $status = $array[2];
        $steamid = $array[3];

    $process = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
       $time = $time - 5;
       $newdata = $wallet . "\n" . $time . "\n" . $status . "\n" . $steamid;
       fwrite($process, $newdata);
    fclose($process);
}
?>
```

Before I execute the script, the files that are opened look like this:

```
680
310
0
74892748232
```

After the script was executed, the file looks like this:

```
680

305
0

74892748232
```

If the script is executed again, it adds more lines and just breaks the files even more.

The string for the file is created here:

```
$newdata = $wallet . "\n" . $time . "\n" . $status . "\n" . $steamid;
```

Why does it add an empty line after $wallet and $status, but not after $time? How can I avoid this and instead write down:

```
$wallet
$time
$status
$steamid
```

Thanks a lot in advance.:)

Comment: Depends on how your OS treats new lines. Try using `$wallet . PHP_EOL . $time` instead.

Comment: it's very useful to set these 2 flags with function file - FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES
and 
FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution

You can also use `file_put_contents()`:

```
file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $array) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

from this SO question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066811/1301180