# I want to save result for looping with enter

Tags: php

I want to save result for looping with enter with this code

```
$str = '';
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $i;    
}

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $str . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

but the result is

```
12345678910
```

I want the result is like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

then I try to use this script

```
$str = '';
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $i . "<br>";    
}

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $str . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

the result like

```
1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
```

anyone can help me to fix this script please ?

Comment: try with  "\r\n"... instead <br>

Comment: You will find answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php
Take a look on this.

Comment: have you tried to add olso \r\n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to simply add the new-line directly within the Loop to get what you want like this:

```
    <?php
        $str = '';
        for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
            $str .= $i . PHP_EOL;   //<== ADD A NEW LINE AT THE END OF EACH DIGIT 
        }

        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        //$txt  = $str . "\n";  //<== YOU WOULDN'T NEED THIS LINE ANYMORE
        fwrite($myfile, $str);
        fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: That's the solution

Comment: @RafaelShkembi     You are one heck of a Team Player... Love that Spirit... Thanks, Mate!!! ;-)

Comment: In the begging i didn't see it but when i view your asnwer i know that was the solution. I think that's the spirit being a team all off us :)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a new line in such a way

try:

```
$txt = $str.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a \r

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $str . "\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Thank's ;-) see you in the asnwers

Answer (score 0):

You save only a var with 12345678910 in your file. If you save every line with a wordwrap it should work. Like this:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    fwrite($myfile, $i . "\n";);  
}

fclose($myfile);
```