# Writing a new and appending a file in PHP without erasing contents

Tags: php, fwrite

How could one write a new line to a file in php without erasing all the other contents of the file?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['songName'])){

        $newLine = "\n";
        $songName = $_POST['songName'];
        $filename = fopen('song_name.txt', "wb");
        fwrite($filename, $songName.$newLine);
        fclose($filename);
    };

?>
```

This is what the file looks like
[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAf7K.png)

This is what is should look like [Ideal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIENb.png)

Comment: Right now the content of the file looks like this 123456789                         It should look like this                                                                                         123                                                                                                                         456                                                                                                                                   789 With each group of 3 numbers on a new line of the file

Comment: try using PHP_EOL instead of "\n"

Comment: Please add the details to your answer, within a code block, so we can see where the line breaks are and where they should be.  This comment also doesn't tell us what was on the file, and what you're trying to append.

Comment: @coder that was exactly what I'm looking for thank you

Comment: glad i could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
file_put_contents($filename,$songName.$newLine,FILE_APPEND);
```

Takes care of opening, writing to, and closing the file. It will even create the file if needed! ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

If your new lines aren't working, the issue is with your `$newLine` variable, not the file append operations.  One of the following will work:

```
$newLine = PHP_EOL;  << or >>  $newLine = "\r\n";
```

Comment: This does not add a new line to the file, it merely appends on to the end of the current line

Comment: @JohnSmith All file append operations, including the other solution, do the same thing.  it appends whatever you indicate. If you want a new line, start with a new line character :-). Eg: append `$newLine.$songName.$newLine`

Comment: @JohnSmith I think it would help if you showed what you're getting, and what you expect to get. Your last comment under the other answer seems to be different from the OP. Do you want to add just one line (as in the OP), or add a new line at the end of each existing line (as in your comment)?

Comment: I attached images of the desired results to be displayed by the file

Comment: That works now, thank you for your help, it is very much appreciated! I Marked yours as the answer!

Comment: @JohnSmith good to know. Suggest you upvote both answers because Robert had the right idea too, just a different approach to appending content.

Answer (score 4):

You have it set for writing with the option `w` which erases the data.

You need to "append" the data like this:

`$filename = fopen('song_name.txt', "a");`

For a complete explanation of what all options do, read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: when set to "a" it does not add new line to the file it merely adds to the end.

Comment: That's not what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to write to a new line in the file without erasing the file's current data

Comment: At a specific position?

Comment: Sure you could say that. I'm trying to add a new line at the end of each line of input.

Comment: I attached images of the desired results to be displayed by the file

Answer (score 2):

To add a new line to a file and append it, do the following

```
$songName = $_POST['songName'];
        $filename = fopen('song_name.txt', "a+");
        fwrite($filename, $songName.PHP_EOL);
        fclose($filename);
```

PHP_EOL will add a new line to the file