# Writing all mysql results into file?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make a program that syncs all the outcome of a row in my mysql database to a .txt file. But it doesnt work. I want each result on a new line.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", "database");


$hwid_query = "SELECT hwid FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $hwid_query);
//$hwids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$hwids = $row['hwid'];
echo $hwids;
}


$fp = fopen('lt.txt', 'w');
ftruncate($fp, 0);
fwrite($fp, $hwids);
fclose($fp);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

This results in one line in the file with only one of the columns of the database, while `echo $hwids;` gives all of them. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The reason you get downvotes is because you miss the "What have you tried?" part. Try to figure out *why* it doesnt work. This is a difficult to learn skill, but after practising a valueable one as it helps debugging later on in your progress.

Answer (score 2):

In the while loop you set `$hwids` to that rows value. The next itteration (eg the next row from the DB) overwrites that same `$hwids` to *it's* value, it overwrites it. At the end of the while, you have the last entry from your result.

There are a few solutions, but in the one below, I write the value to the file per itteration:

```
$file = fopen('lt.txt', 'wb');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $lineToAdd = $row['hwid'] . PHP_EOL; // PHP_EOL = "\n" = Newline
    fwrite($file, $lineToAdd);
}
fclose($file);
```

<sup>I've based this upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Why does everyone disrate my questions?

Comment: I've answered that under your question. On this site, when an posted answer is the solution to a problem, it's normal to mark it as such, so that other people can easily spot the solution when they have the same issue.